# Angular UI button directive, active radio is not getting updated properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the angular ui button directive. I'm trying to make a radio. Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gUyGmb9wRqHYpLWUrBUs?p=preview

Some logic is run when I change an input box. The logic updates the value in the objects which are tied to my radio.

Problem is "$scope.activeInput" is not changed when I update data.

A bit diffuse, but if you go to the plunkr. Hit "specific energy". Write something in the input box. Then you can see that nothing happens in the "my logic" element. If you then hit total cost, then go back to the "specific energy" you can se that the logic gets updated. I want this to happen in realtime. So the "connection" between activeObject and my current selected radio always is updated.

```
$scope.totalCost = {
    title: 'Total cost',
    unit: 'Mkr'
  };

  $scope.specificEnergy = {
    title: 'Specifik energi',
    unit: 'kWh/m2,år'
  };

  $scope.absoluteEnergy = {
    title: 'Absolut energi',
    unit: 'Gwh/år'
  };

  //active input is not getting updated properly
  $scope.activeOutput = $scope.totalCost;

  $scope.$watch('myValue', function(){
    $scope.absoluteEnergy.value = $scope.myValue * 5;
    $scope.specificEnergy.value = $scope.myValue * 15;
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if i hit your problem. But this <kbd>[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/hnuJJZETQMxh5q1EKIYE?p=preview)</kbd> works. I have found two problems:

- the value of btn-radio is evaluated by angular-ui, so you just need to write `btn-radio="totalCost"` instead of `btn-radio="{{totalCost}}"`
- if the `myValue` is changed the `totalCost` `value` is not changed. bit i am not sure what you expect...

Comment: Thank you very much! Been struggling with this all day. Annoying when it was such an easy thing.

Comment: @user1572526 no problem. i knew these kind of situations:)